# How to efficiently draw lots of graphs in R from data in a wide format?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw 18 graphs using R and the ggplot2 package. My data look like this:

```
v1 v2 v3 ... v18 subject group
534 543 512 ... 410 1 (6.5, 18]
437 576 465 ... 420 2 (0, 6.5]
466 487 492 ... 501 3 (18, 55]
```

And I need to create a "faceted" histogram showing distributions for all of the groups in one frame (i. e. to conveniently present all of the subgroups' distributions) like this:

[image: sought after graphs for all 18 variables]

I came up with this code for a single plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = v1)) + geom_histogram (boundary = 500) + facet_wrap(~Group, nrow = 2)
```

But since there are 18 variables (v1, v2,...), I'm looking for a way to write an efficient function/loop/command that would draw all the 18 graphs without me having to copy/paste and change the variable name 18 times.  Like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = **v1**)) + geom_histogram (boundary = 500) + facet_wrap(~Group, nrow = 2)
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = **v2**)) + geom_histogram (boundary = 500) + facet_wrap(~Group, nrow = 2)
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = **v3**)) + geom_histogram (boundary = 500) + facet_wrap(~Group, nrow = 2)
```

I know that the solution probably lies in looping and it seems like a useful skill to have, so I'm also using this opportunity to learn this right.

Thank you, any help is appreciated! (And thanks to all the suggestions so far!)

This is where I've gotten so far with the kind help of the user below:

```
for (v in c(v1,v2)) {
pdf("plots.pdf") 
histograms <- ggplot(data = data, aes (x = v)) + geom_histogram (boundary = 500) + facet_wrap(~Group, nrow = 2) 
print(histograms)
} 
dev.off()
```

Comment: Open an output connection, like `pdf`. Then run the code in a `for` loop. At the end of the loop, while still inside the loop, add the line `print(histograms)` to have the figure output to the pdf. Immediately beneath the loop, add the line `dev.off()` to close the pdf connection.

Comment: I got it running, thank you! Only the printing sucks now – it is only one page with one of the ggplots printed. And they don't look like histograms.

Comment: Petr, your question could be improved by providing more details and a (limited) example of your data. I've guessed at what you're asking and provided an answer with some advice. Good luck.

Comment: Great! I guessed at too complicated a data set. Here's a simple way to convert your data in a data.frame named `wide` to a long format (assuming the only names are 'v1', 'v2',... and 'group'). The new data should work in the answer I provided.
`sel <- which(names(wide) == "group"); dat <- stack(wide[-sel]); names(dat) <- c("v", "Group")`

Comment: I now see that your data appears to have **two** levels of grouping. The first is defined by the variables named 'v1', 'v2', and 'v3'. The second is the variable generated by cutting the values with names that appear to be generated from the `cut()` function: (0, 6.50], (6.5, 18], (18, 55], etc. This latter group appears to be the variable named `Group` in your original question. Again, it would be easier to suggest a solution with information on your data. I'll check back later to see if we can have one more go at it! :)

Comment: I unfortunately cannot divulge the data because of legal issues, I'd love to share  them otherwise. Thank you anyway, you are being absolutely great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196783/discussion-between-david-o-and-petr-palisek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** A significantly revised answer is provided having clarified the needs.

The problem presents several common issues, each of which are addressed in other posts. However, perhaps this suggestion allows for a one-stop solution to these common issues.

My **first suggestion** is to reformat the data into a "long" format. There are many resources describing this and packages to help. Many users embrace the "tidyverse" set of tools and I'll leave that to others. I'll demonstrate a simple approach using base functions. I *don't* recommend the `reshape()` function in the `stats` package. I find it to be useful for repeated measures with time as one of the variables but find it rather complicated for other data.

A large fake data set will be generated in the "wide" format with demographic data `(id, sex, weight, age, group)` and 18 variables named "v01", "v02", ..., "v18" as random integers between 400 and 500.

```
# Set random number generator and number of "individuals" in fake data
  set.seed(1234) # to ensure reproducibility
  N <- 936 # number of "individuals" in the fake data

# Create typical fake demographic data and divide the age into 4 groups
  id <- factor(sample(1e4:9e4, N, replace = FALSE))
  age <- rpois(N, 36)
  sex <- sample(c("F","M"), N, replace = TRUE)
  weight <- 16 * log(age)
  group <- cut(age, breaks = c(12, 32, 36, 40, 62))
```

Generate 18 fake values for each individual for the wide format and then create the fake "wide" data.frame.

```
# 18 variable measurements for wide format
  V <- replicate(18, sample(400:600, N, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
  names(V) <- sprintf("v%02d", 1:18)

# Add a little variation to the fake data
  adj <- sample(1:6, 18, replace = TRUE)
  V <- Map("/", V, adj) # divide each value by the number in 'adj'
  V <- lapply(V, round, 1) # simplify

# Create data.frame with variable data in wide format
  vars <- as.data.frame(V)
  names(vars)

# Assemble demographic and variable data into a typical "wide" data set
  wide <- data.frame(id, sex, weight, age, group, vars)
  names(wide)
  head(wide)
```

In the "wide" format, each row corresponds to a unique individual with demographic information and 18 values for 18 variables. This is going to be changed into the "long" format with each value represented by a row. The new "long" data frame will have two new variables for the data (`values`) and a factor indicating the group from which the data came (`ind`). Typically they get renamed but I will simply work with the default names here.

As noted above, the simple base function `stack()` will be used to stack the variables into a single vector. In contrast to `cbind()`, the `data.frame()` function will replicate values only as long as they are an even multiple of each other. The following code takes advantage of this property to build the "long" data.frame.

```
# Identify those variables to be stacked (they all start with 'v')
  sel <- grepl("^v", names(wide))
  long <- data.frame(wide[!sel], stack(wide[sel]))
  head(long)
```

My **second suggestion** is to use one of the "apply" functions to create a list of `ggplot` objects. By storing the plots in this variable, you have the option of plotting them with different formats without running the plotting code each time.

The code creates a plot for each of the 18 different variables, which are identified by the new variable `ind`. I changed `boundary = 500` to a `bins = 10` since I don't know what your actual data looks like. I also added a "caption" to each plot identifying the original variable.

```
  library(ggplot2) # to use ggplot...
  plotList <- lapply(levels(long$ind), function(i)
    ggplot(data = subset(long, ind == i), aes(x = values))
    + geom_histogram(bins = 10)
    + facet_wrap(~ group, nrow = 2)
    + labs(caption = paste("Variable", i)))
  names(plotList) <- levels(long$ind) # name the list elements for convenience
```

Now to examine each of the 18 plots (this may not work in RStudio):

```
  opar <- par(ask = TRUE)
  plotList # This is the same as print(plotList)
  par(opar) # turn off the 'ask' option
```

To save the plots to file, the advice of Imo is good. But it would be wise to take control of the size and nature of the file output. I suggest you look at the help files for `pdf()` and `dev.print()`. The last part of this answer shows one possibility with the `pdf()` function using a `for` loop to generate single page plots.

```
  for (v in levels(long$ind)) {
    fname <- paste(v, "pdf", sep = ".")
    fname <- file.path("~", fname) # change this to specify a directory
    pdf(fname, width = 6.5, height = 7, paper = "letter")
    print(plotList[[v]])
    dev.off()
  }
```

And just to add another possible approach, here's a solution with `lattice` showing 6 groups of variables per plot. (Personally, I'm a fan of this simpler approach.)

```
  library(lattice)
  idx <- split(levels(long$ind), gl(3, 6, 18))
  opar <- par(ask = TRUE)
  for (i in idx)
    plot(histogram(~values | group + ind, data = long,
      subset = ind %in% i, as.table = TRUE))
  par(opar)
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your help! The code looks great.  However, does it hold even after my clarification of the question? I'm not sure what  you mean by "pairs" and I'm guessing that my inability to write a good question caused a misunderstanding.

Comment: I see. My guess came from the `nrows = 2` option in your code. We can make it clear yet! Your new data shows three groups with values named v1, v2 and v3 although I'm still a little unclear. If your data set isn't too large, perhaps you can use `dput(dat)` or `head(dat)` to show the structure of your data.

Comment: I wanted to do that in the  edit but the output wasn't helpful at all. That's why I opted for a verbal description. It's basically just a couple (18) of measurements per person (v1 etc) and these people are categorized into groups according to their age (group var). And I need to show the distributions for each group in each of the measurements separately.

Comment: We are getting closer! I appreciate the need for privacy but it will help to simulate the data. So, perhaps one more question. And then we can do it! I understand that there are just 18 measurements per person with values roughly in the range of 400 to 500. The individuals are grouped into four age brackets (as shown in your image.) The last question I have is, approximately how many individuals are in your data set? I assumed v1 through v32 but it looks much higher. With this, I could edit my response with some revised suggestions.

Comment: You are so great. It's N = 936. Each person has demographic variables (which we don't care for here), each one has an age bracket stored in the "group" variable and each one has 18 measurements in 18 variables (classic wide format).